# Ferrite placement with TVS and capacitors

Tags: tvs, ferrite-bead

I have to connect some capacitors (1 nF) and TVS diodes after inserting some ferrites as in the figure below.

[image]

I wonder if it might be the same to connect the capacitors and TVS before the ferrites, as below.

[image]

Comment: No, it won't be the same. As to how much different it will be is impossible to tell from the details you have provided.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks, these are two lines used for two 24V digital inputs. If you need further details I am happy to give them

Comment: Here's my recommendation: you simulate the two scenarios to see what the differences are.

Comment: Before or after--what? This is an LCD network, that's all we can say about it.  We have no reference for what it connects to, how it is wired, what it needs to provide filtering for, what impedances are connected. Please add all these information to your question.